# Dispose the Class

Tags: c#, wpf, class, dispose

There is a class in my project called DataParse. I am making multiple connections with Ethernet. Every time a new connection is opened I create a new class as follows. Also, there is one timer in this class.

```
public Dictionary<string, DataParse> classDictionary = new Dictionary<string, DataParse>();
```

Connect Code

```
string IpAddress = Ip.Text;
int Port = Convert.ToInt32(PortName.Text);
var IpPort = IpAddress + ":" + Port;
classDictionary.Add(IpPort, new DataParse());
classDictionary[IpPort].DataParseRun(IpPort);
```

I want to destroy the created class when the connection is closed. I want to destroy the timer with the class.

I implemented a method like this to destroy the class and I failed. He goes into the timer again.

Disconnected Code

```
private void Events_Disconnected(object sender, ClientDisconnectedEventArgs e)
{
    classDictionary[e.IpPort].Dispose();
    classDictionary.Remove(e.IpPort);
}
```

DataParse Code

```
public class  DataParse : IDisposable
    {

    private bool _disposed = false;
    private SafeHandle _safeHandle = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, true);
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
            // Dispose managed state (managed objects).
            _safeHandle?.Dispose();
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }
    
    Timer timer;
    byte[] moduleBuffer;
    int writePtr;
    string key;



    public void DataParseRun(string IpPort)
    {
        moduleBuffer = new byte[50000];
        writePtr = 0;
        timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(ParseTimer), null, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
        key = IpPort;

    }
     
    void ParseTimer(object state)
    {
        var abc = key;    
    }

   
}
```

How can I destroy the class.

Comment: `GC.Collect();` - what this line here for? Also it looks like `_safeHandle` isn't really used.

Comment: saw it in an application. I added it to try. I deleted it now but it still doesn't work.

Comment: How can I use _safeHandle ?

Comment: 1) with `_safeHandle?.` you're increasing cyclomatic complexity, which should be at 1.2) if you're planning to systematically call explicitly a cleanup, do it with a `release()` (or any) function, not with dispose() https://codinghelmet.com/articles/reduce-cyclomatic-complexity-null-object 3) `dispose()` is of good use when you're calling native functions which need to be destroyed; for managed, it is done automatically.

Comment: It was an advanced subject for me. As far as I understand, when a class is not used, it is automatically cleared from memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try manually disposing the timer in the Dispose method. As far as I see the timer is never disposed.

```
timer.Dispose();
```

EDIT: Cant comment yet so Ill edit the answer. As far as I am aware you cant manually just remove your instance from memory.

It will be collected via Garbage Collector once all references to the instance are lost or unreachable - thus once you, as Trix in his answer advises, remove the instance from the Dictionary and dispose of the Timer and SafeHandle there should be nothing stopping the GC from collecting it. However when exactly this happens isn't up to you.

EDIT2: I would say so. You can try to test it by reading some huge file to String to take up 100MB and watch if the memory is let go once you dispose of everything. Apparently there is also a direct call you can make to the GC: GC.Collect() - if you call it from class I don't think it will collect that class but for testing you can call it after you dispose from the dictionary.

Comment: Yes, throwing the timer manually worked. But it just seems like disposing of the timer. How can I make sure I discard the class I created?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand that when I follow the processes you mentioned, the garbage collector will automatically collect them after a certain time. 
So timer.Dispose (); and _safeHangle? .Dispose (); is it enough ?

Comment: I created a function inside the class. After executing the dispose process, I can still access it when I want to access that function. Does this mean that the operation I applied failed?

Comment: Without calling Dispose, DataParse = null; Some time after calling the command, memory is freed. I could not understand.

Comment: So if I understood correctly you have something like 
`DataParse dp = new DataParse(); dp.Dispose(); [SomeCode]...; dp.Somefunction()`. What happens here is you have a reference to the instance of the class thus it cannot be destroyed - thats why I recommended checking memory because as long as you have some reference to the instance you wont be able to destroy it (I think). Without calling Dispose Garbage collection happens eventually and it determines your Object is no longer of use due to not having any references and frees the memory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest. I mark it as an answer. Because disposing of the timer solved my problem. I also believed it would be better to check memory right now.